# jQuery transfer the ID to another element of the same parent

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-lists

With this code every `<ul>` with `class="myDropDown"` have the same result. My problem is to the `var getID`. I want every `<div class="dropDownInner">` to get the ID of the `<ul>` from which it was created. How can i fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var getID = $(".myDropDown").attr('id');
  $(".myDropDown").wrap('<div class="customDropDown"></div>');
  $(".customDropDown").prepend('<div class="dropDownHeader">');
  $(".dropDownHeader").append('<div class="dropDownInner" id="' + getID + '">Select One</div>');
  $(".dropDownHeader").append('</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="myDropDown" id='testSelect'>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="myDropDown" id='testList'>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. What you're trying to do makes no sense.

Comment: Anyway, to do what you want, you have to loop through each `.myDropDown`. Use `this.id` to get its ID, and use `$(this)` when adding the wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is how you can get the ID associated with each `ul` element.

```
$('.myDropDown').each(function(index) {
    // Execute the below code for each element with class .myDropdown
    var id = $(this).closest('ul.myDropDown').attr('id');  
    $(this).wrap('<div class="customDropDown"></div>');
    $(this).prepend('<div class="dropDownHeader">');
    $(this).closest('div').prepend('<div class="dropDownInner" id="' + id + '">Select One</div>');
    $(this).append('</div>');
});
```

This has the same DOM structure as your code, with the distinct IDs you were looking for

Edit: Barmar has made a fair point. ID's should be used only once on each page. I'd recommend changing the ID to a class. This would involve a little more code, however.

Comment: This is it !! I changed the code a bit but the root of the solution is this. Thank you. Also i need the id so i used this `$(this).removeAttr("ID");`